# белый неработающий код в Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

После сохранения файла и его переименовывания в "Булочки", и последующего открытия через некоторое время, некоторая часть кода стала белой и неработающей, а при вызове консоли в неё ничего не выводится, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как её исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в C# нужно не просто сохранять код в файл, а создавать проект, чтобы был хотя бы какой-то базовый csproj файл, тогда VS будет правильно все отображать и позволит его запустить

Comment: У вас открыт cs файл как текст, а надо открывать проект